# Why do I get throwtransaction error?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, sol

This is my script:

```
    import * as web3 from '@solana/web3.js';

import * as fs from 'fs';

import {
  ExtensionType,
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
  createAccount,
  createInitializeMintInstruction,
  createInitializeTransferFeeConfigInstruction,
  getMintLen,
  getTransferFeeAmount,
  harvestWithheldTokensToMint,
  mintTo,
  transferCheckedWithFee,
  unpackAccount,
  withdrawWithheldTokensFromAccounts,
  withdrawWithheldTokensFromMint,
} from "@solana/spl-token";

import {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  SystemProgram,
  Transaction,
  clusterApiUrl,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";

// Connection to the devnet cluster
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

const myKeypairFile = "./keypair.json";
const tokenKeypairFile = "./tokenpair.json";
const tokenAccountKeyfile = "./tokenaccount.json";
const destinationAccountKeyfile = "./destination.json";
const signer = loadWalletKey(myKeypairFile);
const tokenKey = loadWalletKey(tokenKeypairFile);
const tokenAcckountKey = loadWalletKey(tokenAccountKeyfile);
const destinationAccountKey = loadWalletKey(destinationAccountKeyfile);

export function loadWalletKey(keypairFile:string): web3.Keypair {
  if (!keypairFile || keypairFile == '') {
    throw new Error('Keypair is required!');
  }
  const loaded = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(
    new Uint8Array(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(keypairFile).toString())),
  );
  return loaded;
}

const MINT_EXTENSIONS = [ExtensionType.TransferFeeConfig];

const mint = tokenKey.publicKey;

async function createTFToken(){
    const mintLen = getMintLen(MINT_EXTENSIONS);
    const mintLamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(mintLen);
    const mintTransaction = new Transaction().add(
        SystemProgram.createAccount({
            fromPubkey: signer.publicKey,
            newAccountPubkey: mint,
            space: mintLen,
            lamports: mintLamports,
            programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        }),
        createInitializeTransferFeeConfigInstruction(
            mint,
            signer.publicKey,
            signer.publicKey,
            100,
            BigInt(1000000000),
            TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
        ),
        createInitializeMintInstruction(mint, 9, signer.publicKey, null, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID)
    );
    const txid = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, mintTransaction, [signer, tokenKey], undefined);
    console.log(txid);
}

async function mintSome(){
  const firstRun = false;
  if(firstRun){
    const sourceAccount = await createAccount(
        connection,
        signer,
        mint,
        signer.publicKey,
        tokenAcckountKey,
        undefined,
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
    );
  }
console.log(tokenAcckountKey.publicKey);
console.log(connection);
console.log(mint);
console.log(signer.publicKey);



await mintTo(
    connection,
    signer,
    mint,
    tokenAcckountKey.publicKey,
    signer.publicKey,
    42000000000,
    [],
    undefined,
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
);
}

async function sendTokensWithTransferFee() {
  
  const firstRun = false;
  if(firstRun){
      const destinationAccount = await createAccount(
        connection,
        signer,
        mint,
        signer.publicKey,
        destinationAccountKey,
        undefined,
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
      );
    }

    // Fee basis points for transfers (100 = 1%)
    const feeBasisPoints = 5000;
    // Maximum fee for transfers in token base units
    const maxFee = BigInt(5000);

    // Transfer amount
    const transferAmount = BigInt(1000_00);
    // Calculate transfer fee
    const fee = (transferAmount * BigInt(feeBasisPoints)) / BigInt(10_000);
    // Determine fee charged
    const feeCharged = fee > maxFee ? maxFee : fee;

    const decimals = 2;
    
    const txid = await transferCheckedWithFee(
      connection,
      signer,
      tokenAcckountKey.publicKey,
      mint,
      destinationAccountKey.publicKey,
      signer,
      fee,
      decimals,
      feeCharged,
      undefined,
      undefined,
      TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
    );
    console.log(txid)
    
}


async function printAmount(tokenAccount:web3.PublicKey) {
    const taInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(tokenAccount);
    const amount = taInfo?.data.readBigInt64LE(2*32);
    console.log(tokenAccount.toBase58()+ " holds "+amount);
}

async function main() {
    console.log(signer.publicKey)
    console.log("let's create a transfer fee enabled token ;D");
    createTFToken();

    console.log("let's mint some!");
    await mintSome();

    console.log("SEND IT!");
    await sendTokensWithTransferFee();

    printAmount(tokenAcckountKey.publicKey);
    printAmount(destinationAccountKey.publicKey);

}

main();
```

This is the error that I get:

```
throw new SendTransactionError('failed to send transaction: ' + res.error.message, logs);
            ^

SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x0
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (C:\Users\Ben\Documents\freelance\Solana\token\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:8026:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (C:\Users\Ben\Documents\freelance\Solana\token\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:7992:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (C:\Users\Ben\Documents\freelance\Solana\token\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:7983:12)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (C:\Users\Ben\Documents\freelance\Solana\token\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:2160:21) {
  logs: [
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Create Account: account Address { address: BggYSHrgLwvSWkALt9GPuZcUExbjxFaLgCMayywX5Rei, base: None } already in use',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 failed: custom program error: 0x0'
  ]
}
```

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your error logs, it says

`'Create Account: account Address { address: BggYSHrgLwvSWkALt9GPuZcUExbjxFaLgCMayywX5Rei, base: None } already in use',`

In other words, you're trying to create a token that already exists (probably because you created it on earlier runs of your code). Remove the code that creates the mint and just run the code to send and you should be fine.